# Unable to send email with php..!

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I created a script with php/code igniter that must send email in a stage.
Previously email sending was sucsessfull but now not!
I have installed CSF firewall on my VPS,it seems problem is occured by this firewall, is it true?

Comment: Disable the firewall and try again. That will clear one thing off the list

Comment: List = Things that could be creating a problem

Comment: I know,but there is what items in this list?

Comment: To know its contents, we would need to see your code. Otherwise it's impossible to say what could be the problem. But start with disabling your firewall.

Comment: Thanks but my code is very simple.Send email with codeIgniter framework

Comment: It could still be any number of things.  If you don't post your code, there isn't any way we can really help you.  And for the third time, please start with disabling your firewall.

Comment: At this time im in university an dont have access to ssh!but this is my code:                                              $this->load->library('email');

     $this->email->from('noreply@xxxxx', 'xxxx');
     $this->email->to($useremail); 
     $this->email->cc(''); 
     $this->email->bcc(''); 

     $this->email->subject('ddddddd');
     $this->email->message("xxxxxxx"); 

     $this->email->send();

Answer (score 2):

If sending emails worked before using the same setup and you are sure it is the firewall that came inbetween, well then most likely it is the firewall causing the problems. So you have to answer yourself these questions:

- what network connection is done whilst sending the email? That one is probably blocked by the firewall.
- what protocol/port is used inside this network connection, so used to send emails? Depends on your configuration, actually, which you don't name here, so you have to check yourself. Most likely it is `smtp`, that would be port 25.
- why might that connection be blocked by the new firewall? Well, depends on the firewalls configuration obviously. Only you can check and change.
- maybe there is some log file you can consult? Depends on the configuration and the type of firewall you use, I'd say. Maybe you have to raise the logging level.
- and and and

Without us knowing any details it is only you who can answer those questions and find the problem. On the other hand this helps you learning your way in networking technology. Which is a great thing. Go on!